# AsymmetricGridView change vertical dividers color

Tags: android, gridview, divider

I'm using the AsymmetricGridView lib, and i'm strugling to change the vertical dividers color.

My XML:

```
<com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>
```

But this divider property is only for horizontal dividers. The vertical ones stays white.

My objective it's to put them transparent to see the image in the background.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @felipecsl do you have solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: oh god, after 4 years nobody solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I have correct answer. Please copy item_divider_horizontal.xml and item_divider_vertical.xml file to your drawable folder of your project. And please change the color inside the xml files. 
You can find these files in this link:
https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/tree/master/library/src/main/res/drawable